Trying to have 2 labels function on one time
I am trying to have 2 labels handled by one timer. They both update with random number generator from 0 to 99. I am trying to get it to only stop updating the one clicked and allow the other to continue updating but I can't get it to work. Here is the code snippet:
    bool updateLabel1 = true;
    bool updateLabel2 = true;

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (updateLabel1)
            label1.Text = random.Next(10).ToString();
        if (updateLabel2)
            label2.Text = random.Next(10).ToString();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateLabel1 = false;
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateLabel2 = false;
    }


I just ran your code locally on my PC, do you run the timer1.Start(); command?
In addition, random.Next(10) will generate random numbers in [0, 9], and not [0, 99]

"can't get it to work" - what exactly is not working ? We need some more details. Did you try to debug ?

You need to store updateLabel1 and updateLabel2 in a Session or ViewState, otherwise they won't survive the page life cycle.

In addition to checking if the Timer is enabled, are the Click() events of the Labels properly assigned to your click handlers? Is the Tick() event of the Timer wired up to your code?

@VDWWD The question is tagged winforms, not webforms. There is no need for those in winforms.

Make sure Timer_Tick method is assigned to your timer Tick event(such as timer1).
To make the timer work, you just need to add: timer1.Start();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       //after initialize
        timer1.Start();
    }

random number generator from 0 to 99:
random.Next(100).ToString();
Update:
  private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      updateLabel1 = false;
      updateLabel2 = true;
  }

  private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      updateLabel2 = false;
      updateLabel1 = true;
  }
     


I have those actually I only provided a snippet sorry. The issue is I want the timer to continue for the other label when the other one is for instance clicked

@mtom  ,Hi, I updated the answer. Please check it. Switch the value of two labels.
